# Mistake with hook holder (steering arm with round socket) on Technic Helicopter 42145

Tags: technic, building

I made one small (but costly) mistake in my otherwise very satisfying build for the Airbus helicopter: at step 66, I connected the grey piece "steering arm with ball socket" the wrong way. And of course now that I need it at step 744(!), the socket is facing up instead of down, and it is impossible to attach the hook. Can anyone here see a not-too-painful way of fixing this? Otherwise I will just have to give up on that hook.
Thanks!

[image: step 66]
[image: step 744]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see from building step 66 and 67 the beam is held with a length 7 axle and a blue length 3 pin.

I'm afraid there is no easy way to flip that beam without partially deconstructing the model.

You can deconstruct either severely on one side until you can access the axle and take it out with pliers, or less severely on both sides so you can push the axle through with another axle.

Likely the blue pin will not give you much trouble, if the model is deconstructed enough to remove the yellow axle, there will be enough wiggle room to force out the beam with pin and all, Lego Technic is rather flexible like that.

One tip to make the process less painful: photograph each step you did while deconstructing the model. Then reverse the order of the pictures and you'll have yourself a list of instructions to put the model back together.

Comment: That's good advice even it it won't be easy for me to fix it. Thanks!